# Keyframe all bones in armature at once?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, keyframes, timeline

How do I keyframe the location, rotation and scale for all bones in an armature at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all bones in pose mode,
Press I and T to insert keyframes for LocRotScale (i.e. location, rotation, scale)

Answer (score 2):

Select the bones you want to keyframe, then change the mode from `Object Mode` to `Pose Mode`.

[image: Pose Mode]

Then, once you are satisfied with editing your bones, press <kbd>I</kbd> and then click on `LocRotScale`.

[image: Adding the keyframe]

This will add a keyframe for the location, rotation and scaling for all selected bones. I suggest you read [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/index.html).